# <select> tag returns an empty value to the database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

So I am trying to create a  dropdown that loops through $countries and then the selected country is written to $country in the database under the user table. I got the dropdown, but it returns a null value to the database (well the validation at least).

Here is the call for the dropdown

```
       <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
        <label for="country">Country</label>
        <div id="countrydd">
          @if(isset($currentCountry->name))
            <select name="country" id="country_display" class="current-value-da-select closed">
                {{(isset($user->country->name))?$user->country->name:$currentCountry->name}}
                @foreach($countries as $country)
                    <option value="{{$country->name}}">{{$country->name}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>

          @else
            <select name="country" id="country_display" class="current-value-da-select closed">
                {{(isset($user->country->name))?$user->country->name:'Select your Country'}}
                @foreach($countries as $country)
                    <option value="{{$country->name}}">{{$country->name}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>

          @endif
```

And this is the Javascript for the dropdown

```
   //Country Drop Down
$('#countrydd').click(function(e) {
  var selectWrapperCountry = $('#countrydd');
  var currentValueCountry = $(this).find('a').html();
  selectWrapperCountry.find('.current-value-da-select').html(currentValueCountry);
  selectWrapperCountry.find('#country').val(currentValueCountry);
  updateCarretClassCountry();
});
$('#countrydd a.current-value-da-select').click(function() {
  updateCarretClassCountry();
});
function updateCarretClassCountry(){
  if($('#countrydd a.current-value-da-select').hasClass('closed')) {
    $('#countrydd a.current-value-da-select').attr('class', 'current-value-da-select opened');
  }
  else
  {
    $('#countrydd a.current-value-da-select').attr('class', 'current-value-da-select closed');
  }
};
```

Any help to get the value to update right would be awesome.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are using the select tag wrong. Select needs to have a name (that is what you will get as a post variable), and every option needs to have a value. So it would be something like this:

```
<select name="country">
  <option value="1">First one</option>
  <option value="2">Second one</option>
</select>
```

After the form is submitted, you would have

```
echo $_POST["country"]; //This will output 1 if First one is selected and 2 if Second one is
```

Also, why do you have `<a>` inside `<option>` ?

Read more at: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/select

Comment: Also, `<option>` cannot containg a link, nor any other HTML tag (afaik).

Comment: How about `<option value="{{$country->name}}">{{$country->name}}</option>`

Comment: I copied the wrong code. I edited to the proper <select> syntax with the same results.

Comment: Then you should include FORM element, and generated html in fiddle, if possible